# How can the recipients and content for comment email notifications on a custom post type be changed?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, email, notifications

I am building a ticket system and would like to use the comment threads as the discussion for the ticket. There are three users involved in each ticket:

1. The client.
2. The support operator.
3. The support supervisor.

The order of things is:

1. Client opens ticket
2. Supervisor assigns it to operator.
3. Operator works on it.

All three can add to the discussion and I would like to notify the other two with a custom message, when one adds a comment. How can I do this?

Comment: Absolutely a great feature you are trying. Let me tell you one thing. But I dont have answer for your big question. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1373  here is the core functions with action hooks. so try interpret and come up with your desired code.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the long way, with help from [a related WordPress.org support thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-email-recipient-in-comments-notification-e-mail?replies=3):

```
add_action('comment_post', 'notify_author_of_reply', 10, 2);

function notify_author_of_reply($comment_id, $approved){

  $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
  $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
  $post = get_post($post_id);

  if($approved && (get_post_type( $post_id )=='ticket')) {

    $supervisor = get_userdata( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assigned_by', true) );
    $operator = get_userdata( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assigned_to', true) );
    $client = get_userdata( $post->post_author );

    $recipients = array(
      $client->user_email,
      $supervisor->user_email,
      $operator->user_email
    );

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (($key = array_search($current_user->user_email, $recipients)) !== false) {
      unset($recipients[$key]);
    }
    wp_mail($recipients, 'New comment', 'Dude you got a reply...');
  }
}
```